# Lack of spacing in table due to text blurring into the borders

Tags: tables, spacing

Following is my Latex template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
S. No. & Analysis \\ \hline
$1$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ \hline
$2$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ \hline
$2$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ \hline
$2$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ \hline
$3$ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt},$\\ $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$\end{tabular} \\ \hline
$3$ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt},$\\ $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$\end{tabular} \\ \hline
$3$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ \hline
$3$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example of a table}
\label{sth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This generates the following table.

[image]

My problem is that the table looks shabby. It looks very cluttered. Is there some way to put some gap in each of the boxes between the text and the box borders. The problem is only with the elements of the second column because those have a formula with both superscript and subscript.

What is the most beautiful way to publish this table so that people can read it easily?

PS: I need to keep it to footnotesize. But I don't think that should matter. All I am asking how to put some white space around the formula in the second column so that the formula does into blend into the borders.

Comment: unrelated but `\begin{table}[]` means "do not allow the table anywhere" latex warns about that `LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier. Default added (so using \`tbp') on input line 9.` but it is better to use `\begin{table}` and avoid the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would (a) employ an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment for the main table, (b) I wouldn't use the 'inner' `tabular` environments at all, (c) I'd use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package for fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines, and (d) omit all vertical lines; they're not needed -- really!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, \addlinespace
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\mbox{S.\,No.} & \mbox{Analysis} \\ 
\midrule
1 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \addlinespace
1 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \addlinespace
1 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \addlinespace
2 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \addlinespace
2 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \addlinespace
2 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \addlinespace
3 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt},\\[0.5ex]
&x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \addlinespace
3 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt},\\[0.5ex]
&x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \addlinespace
3 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \addlinespace
3 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\caption{Example of a table}
\label{sth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up query:

> Is there a way to compress things a little bit more so that this takes the same space as the original one while retaining the aesthetics?

The main point of inserting some extra vertical space between rows, via the `\addlinespace` instructions, was to change the aesthetics, by creating a bit of "breathing space" inside the table. How to retain these aethetics while saving some vertical space isn't going to be straightforward. I suppose that executing `\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{0.3em}` immediately before `$\begin{array}...`, and changing the two instances of `\\[0.5ex]` to `\\0.3ex`, should manage the preserve at least some of the aesthetics. Plus, you'll save about two rows of vertical space... The following screenshot juxtaposes the solution shown above with the one that results from reducing the value of `\defaultaddspace` by 40%. (In case you're curious: eliminating the `\addlinespace` directives entirely -- which would definitely affect the aesthetics in a major way! -- would save another 1 to 2 rows.)

[image]

Comment: it was very difficult to choose one out of all the answers. i picked this one.

Comment: Is there a way to compress things a little bit more so that this takes the same space as the original one while retaining the aesthetics? I am short on space for my paper.

Comment: @user_1_1_1 - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: Thanks. Could you take a stab at [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479381/73144) too?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the `booktabs`  and the `cellspace` package you can achieve the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
            \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
            \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{SlSc}
\toprule
S. No. & Analysis \\ 
\midrule
$1$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ 
$1$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ 
$1$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ 
$2$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ 
$2$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ 
$2$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ 
$3$ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt},$\\[3pt] $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$\end{tabular} \\ 
$3$ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt},$\\[3pt] $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$\end{tabular} \\ 
$3$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ 
$3$ & $x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}$ \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example of a table}
\label{sth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it better with the help of `cellspace` and `makecell`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\footnotesize
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{|l| >{$}Sc<{$}|}
\hline
S. No. & \text{Analysis} \\ \hline
 1 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \hline
 1 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \hline
 1 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \hline
 2 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \hline
 2 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \hline
 2 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \hline
 3 & \makecell{x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}, \\[0.5ex] x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}} \\ \hline
 3 & \makecell{x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}, \\[0.5ex] x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}} \\ \hline
 3 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \hline
 3 & x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt}+x^c_{pq}+p^{34r}_{rt} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example of a table}
\label{sth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]