# Lack of spacing in a complex table structure

Tags: tables

Following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479175/73144), I have another table in latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 3pt}}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!t]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Example of a table}
\label{sth}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}Sc<{$}|>{$}Sc<{$}|>{$}Sc<{$}|>{$}Sc<{$}|>{$}Sc<{$}|>{$}Sc<{$}?>{$}Sc<{$}|>{$}Sc<{$}|>{$}Sc<{$}|>{$}Sc<{$}|>{$}Sc<{$}|}
\cline{2-11}
 & \multicolumn{5}{c?}{X^{tr} (\mathrm{english text})} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Y^{yu} (\mathrm{english text})} \\ \cline{2-11} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{} & \mathscr{A}_1 & \mathscr{A}_2 & \mathscr{A}_3 & \mathscr{A}_4 & \mathscr{A}_5 & \mathscr{A}_1 & \mathscr{A}_2 & \mathscr{A}_3 & \mathscr{A}_4 & \mathscr{A}_5 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have multiple problems with my effort.

1. why does -2* appear in the first column?
2. I tried to get rid of vertical and horizontal lines but I need to retain a bold black divider in the middle. so, I don't know which lines to delete.
3. the formulas are blurring into the lines so should I remove lines. I tried to give an extra gap around each box. is there a better way? my method does not seem to work for the first row at the top.
4. The "english text" does not appear in the second row as it should with space in between. what I tried is to write everything in the table as a math formula but this is generating errors. can someone sort this out?
5. In the second row, the A should appear as a script capital. That is not happening.

Mainly I need help to make this table more readable and resolve the error messages that are generated. Please suggest changes.

Comment: The `\multirow{-2}{*}{}` directive appears to be at fault. What exactly is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments and observations:

- Since virtually all of the table's material is supposed to be in math mode, use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment.
- The `c` column type would appear to be appropriate for all 11 columns. The `cellspace` package does have its uses. For the present table, though, to employ its machinery appears to be overkill.
- To reduce the overall width of the table, change the value of `\arraycolsep` (assuming you've followed my advice to use an `array` environment). The default value of this parameter is `5pt`; in the example below, I set it to `2.5pt`.
- The "-2" string appears because of the `\multirow{-2}{*}{}` directive. What is it supposed to achieve? The table does just fine without it.
- Your table is ok without *any* vertical lines. Really. See below.
- Use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` and `\cline`.
- Don't use `\mathrm`; use either `\text{...}` or `\textnormal{...}`.
- To make the `\mathscr` macro behave as expected, load a package that provides a math-script math alphabet. Try the `mathrsfs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools,array,mathrsfs,booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\newcommand\msA{\mathscr{A}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\setlength\arraycolsep{2.5pt} % default value: 5pt
\footnotesize
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize} % optional
\centering
\caption{Example of a table}
\label{sth}
$\begin{array}{@{}*{11}{c}@{}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{X^{tr} (\textnormal{english text})} 
 & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{Y^{yu} (\text{english text})} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(l){7-11}
 & \msA_1 & \msA_2 & \msA_3 & \msA_4 & \msA_5 
 & \msA_1 & \msA_2 & \msA_3 & \msA_4 & \msA_5 \\ 
\midrule
1 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 
  & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35  \\ 
2 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 
  & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

[image]

If it is here's the code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=setB,StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 3pt}}
    \begin{table}[!t]
        \footnotesize
        \centering
        \caption{Example of a table}
        \label{sth}
        \begin{tabular}{>{$}Sc<{$}>{$}Sc<{$}>{$}Sc<{$}>{$}Sc<{$}>{$}Sc<{$}>{$}Sc<{$}?>{$}Sc<{$}>{$}Sc<{$}>{$}Sc<{$}>{$}Sc<{$}>{$}Sc<{$}}
            & \multicolumn{5}{c?}{$X^{tr} (\mathrm{english text})$} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$Y^{yu} (\mathrm{english text})$} \\
             & \mathscr{A}_1 & \mathscr{A}_ 2 & \mathscr{A}_3 & \mathscr{A}_4 & \mathscr{A}_5 & \mathscr{A}_1 & \mathscr{A}_2 & \mathscr{A}_3 & \mathscr{A}_4 & \mathscr{A}_5 \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35  \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35 & 5413.35  \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

1. Because of the `\multirow{-2}{*}{}`. Your code wasn't compiling because you didn't had the package `multirow`.
2. Delete all the `|`.
3. Your choice
4. It's because it's in math mode, so you need to manually add a space, using `\,`
5. You hadn't defined the command to make the letters in script mode.